# How to setup docker squid container and host to route requests from container host to internet?

Tags: docker, networking, proxy, squid

Right now I have a docker container running squid listening on a range of ports.  I ran it using the following command so that the port range is published to the host as well.

```
docker run -ti -v /var/log/squid:/var/log/squid -p 3133-3168:3133-3168 my_image/squid_test4 -name squid
```

I am trying to setup this up so clients can hit the container host on a port within the port range described above and still get out to the internet.

From the container host I can run `curl -x http://172.17.x.x:3134 http://ipinfo.io` and get out no problem.  Whenever I try to use the hosts ip (ie `curl -x http://host_ip:3134 http://ipinfo.io`) on a client it hangs and times out.  I can see the request hit the host via tcpdump but nothing is returned.

When I run `netstat -tlpn` on the host I can see entries saying that docker is listening on the port range I specify.  When I am on a client and do something like `telnet host_ip 3134` it connects and tells me something is listening there.

Do I need to setup iptables PREROUTE NAT on the host to forward traffic to those ports or could I use something like HA proxy on the host and set the squid container up as a backend?  Kind of stumped here...

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, simple check and noticed iptables/ufw not running.  However when I did `iptables -L` or `iptables-save` they showed current in memory rules.  Restarted UFW all good now...now I feel dumb.